# Min and maxdate on p:datePicker (or p:calendar) causes ClassCastException or minimum date must be less than maximum date

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Am using PrimeFaces 10.0.0. I need to dynamically set the `maxdate` to be 10 years from now when using `p:datePicker` with a fixed `mindate`.

Utility bean to set `maxdate`:

```java
@Named @ApplicationScoped
public class Dates {

    public LocalDate getLocalDateNow() {
        return LocalDate.now();
    }
}
```

Date picker:

```html
<p:datePicker pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
              mindate="1/1/2011"
              maxdate="#{dates.localDateNow.plusYears(10)}"
              .../>
```

Throws this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate
    at java.time.LocalDate.compareTo(LocalDate.java:137)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UICalendar.validateMinMax(UICalendar.java:375)
    at org.primefaces.component.calendar.BaseCalendarRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseCalendarRenderer.java:84)
    at org.primefaces.component.datepicker.DatePickerRenderer.encodeEnd(DatePickerRenderer.java:89)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:619)
    ...
```

When I changed my utility bean to return a `String`:

```java
public String getLocalDateNow() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu");
    LocalDate localDateNow = LocalDate.now().plusYears(10);
    return localDateNow.format(dtf);
}
```

And subsequently:

```html
maxdate="#{dates.localDateNow}"
```

This is what happens:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: DatePicker : "form:startDate" minimum date must be less than maximum date.
    ...
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: DatePicker : "form:serviceStart" minimum date must be less than maximum date.
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UICalendar.validateMinMax(UICalendar.java:378)
    at org.primefaces.component.calendar.BaseCalendarRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseCalendarRenderer.java:84)
    at 
    ...
```

How can I prevent these exceptions?

Comment: Just change `mindate="1/1/2011"` to `mindate="#{dates.minLocalDate}"` and it will work.

Comment: This didn't work because the ```Dates``` class did not contain a ```minLocalDate``` as a class member / field.

Comment: He was implying you should add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [source code of `UICalendar.validateMinMax`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/d8acc5196925c234c69c143036b02619a72d0eb9/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/api/UICalendar.java#L372-L380):

```java
public void validateMinMax(FacesContext context) {
    Comparable minDate = (Comparable) getMindate();
    Comparable maxDate = (Comparable) getMaxdate();
    if (minDate != null && maxDate != null && maxDate.compareTo(minDate) < 0) {
        String id = getClientId(context);
        String component = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        throw new FacesException(component + " : \"" + id + "\" minimum date must be less than maximum date.");
    }
}
```

It simply checks for `Comparable` and does not care about the actual type. If you are using `LocalDate` for one date and `String` for the other, comparing will lead to an error (as shown in your first stack trace).

Using `String` for both is also no good, as comparing strings has nothing to do with a date value. It might, if you would use a date pattern like `yyyy-MM-dd`, but it's better not to use strings.

You should use the same (non-string) type (for example `LocalDate`) for both min and max dates and it will work.

That being said, the current implementation of `validateMinMax` is flawed. This has already been reported (and fixed while writing this answer):

- Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7576
- Fix: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/7637

Fix will end up in PrimeFaces 11.

By the way, this code is shared with the `p:calendar` component, so the same principle applies there. Note though that `p:calendar` is deprecated!

Comment: The PR for this fix has been merged.

Comment: @Jasper - Setting the ```mindate="#{dates.localDateNow.minusYears(10)}"``` fixed the ```maxdate="#{dates.localDateNow.plusYears(10)}"```  - great explanation!

Comment: @Melloware - What will the PR merged fix? Comparison with Strings?

Comment: All the issues explained above